# Pointer and slice reference type - receiver

Tags: go

I think this will be a bit obvious once it's called out to me, but right now the following isn't clicking.

```
type Stack []interface{}

func (stack *Stack) Push(x interface{}) {
    *stack = append(*stack, x)
}
```

I have a type called Stack that is a slice of empty interfaces.  Given that it's empty, the Push method satisfies the interface.  Given that a slice is a reference type, why can't the 'stack' receiver just be passed in by value?  Furthermore, in the example above the receiver is passed as a pointer why does the append built-in need to be passed by pointer again?

IE why wouldn't this work, given that the slice is a reference pointer to an underlying array?

```
func (stack Stack) Push(x interface{}) {
    stack = append(stack, x)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [article on the Go blog](http://blog.golang.org/slices). It explains in detail what is happening and fully answers your question.

From the section **Passing slices to functions**:

> It's important to understand that even though a slice contains a pointer, it is itself a value. Under the covers, it is a struct value holding a pointer and a length. It is not a pointer to a struct.

As a result you either need a pointer receiver or you need to return the slice as a value if you want to modify it with `append`.

If you just want to modify the contents of a slice you can simply pass the slice by value:

> Even though the slice header is passed by value, the header includes a
>   pointer to elements of an array, so both the original slice header and
>   the copy of the header passed to the function describe the same array.
>   Therefore, when the function returns, the modified elements can be
>   seen through the original slice variable.

With `append` you are modifying the slice header. And

> Thus if we want to write a function that modifies the header, we must
>   return it as a result parameter

Or:

> Another way to have a function modify the slice header is to pass a pointer to it.

You also seem to have a confusion on the use of pointers. See the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x.

And:

> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x.

Thus your example `*stack = append(*stack, x)` doesn't mean that you are passing a pointer to `append`, quite the opposite - you are dereferencing the pointer to pass the value it's pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that `append` returns a reference to the new slice. You cannot change the value of the function's receiver unless it is a pointer.

What I would recommend rather is making a wrapper struct:

```
type Stack struct{
   data []interface{}
   size int
}
func (s *Stack) Push(i interface{}){
   s.data = append(s.data,i)
   s.size++
}
```

Comment: The `struct` makes it easier to understand, but the `size` field here is completely redundant and requires unnecessary work to maintain it, as you can just get it by `len(data)`.

Comment: I agree. It was mostly to demonstrate the advantage over a raw slice in that you can add additional data as you need.