# Map as a method receiver

Tags: go

Does anyone know why map can be used as a value receiver, but when working with slices only the pointer receiver can be used? **Why the map is changing after the method call?**

Example for map:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type hashMap map[string]int

func (s hashMap) Add(k string, v int) {
    s[k] = v
}

func main() {
    var s hashMap
    s = make(hashMap, 0)
    fmt.Println(s)
    s.Add("abc", 15)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
map[]
map[abc:15]
```

Example for slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type slice []int

func (s *slice) Add(v int) {
    (*s) = append(*s, v)
}

func main() {
    var s slice
    s = make(slice, 0)
    fmt.Println(s)
    s.Add(15)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
[]
[15]
```

Comment: Slices with value receivers are commonly used, see the [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838240/pointer-and-slice-reference-type-receiver

Comment: slices point to array and not change its index on adding new value. While map index are arbitrary they change the address of original value on adding new value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A map variable, after make, is a pointer to the map header: `*hmap`. The map pointer is passed by value

```
// A header for a Go map.
type hmap struct {
    // Note: the format of the Hmap is encoded in ../../cmd/internal/gc/reflect.go and
    // ../reflect/type.go. Don't change this structure without also changing that code!
    count     int // # live cells == size of map.  Must be first (used by len() builtin)
    flags     uint8
    B         uint8  // log_2 of # of buckets (can hold up to loadFactor * 2^B items)
    noverflow uint16 // approximate number of overflow buckets; see incrnoverflow for details
    hash0     uint32 // hash seed

    buckets    unsafe.Pointer // array of 2^B Buckets. may be nil if count==0.
    oldbuckets unsafe.Pointer // previous bucket array of half the size, non-nil only when growing
    nevacuate  uintptr        // progress counter for evacuation (buckets less than this have been evacuated)

    extra *mapextra // optional fields
}
```

A slice variable is a struct: `slice`. The slice struct is passed by value.

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

Comment: Thank youf for expanation! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @peterSO  Can you add the source please!

Answer (score 0):

Map is receiver type while struct is value type,Value type. Hence when you call using map value changes after function call.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the difference between map and slice internal representation. There is no such thing as "receiver type" in Go (AFAIK).